# Why is my vector not initializing as expected?

Tags: c++

```
vector<string> grid();

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
     string hello(10, '.');
     grid.push_back(hello);
}

vector<int> newVec(grid.size(), 0);

for(int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
{
     if(grid[0][i] = '.')
            newVec[i] == 1;
}
```

You would expect that newVec would now have all of its elements equal to 1.  But I keep getting all 0s.  Any help?

Comment: This code compiles? "`this`" is a keyword.

Comment: Sorry, changed.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Also your loop only seems to set the first 7 to 1.

Comment: @user1038665, for later reference, it's better to post complete (but minimal!) snippets that actually compile. `this` is not the only problem in your code -- the very first line in your snippet declares a function.

Answer (score 8):

At least two things are wrong:

- You probably want `if(grid[0][i] = '.')` to be `if(grid[0][i] == '.')`. This is not the cause of the problem, though.
- You want `newVec[i] == 1;` to be `newVec[i] = 1;`. That one is the source of why the elements in `newVec` are not having their values set to 1.

Comment: +1 and deleted mine, good job spotting the assignment in the condition!